# Nothing happens when I do: python manage.py command

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm new to django and currently going through the main tutorial. Even though it was working earlier, when I do python manage.py runserver OR python manage.py -h OR with any other command, the shell doesn't output anything. Wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If it was working earlier and stop working which mean that you changed something that "broke" ``manage.py`` !? I guess.

Comment: We're going to need more info to help. What is your directory structure? What is your current working directory when running the command? Did you move manage.py before it broke? Is there any output at all? Python in a virtual env or site-wide?

Comment: Hey guys, this was a horrible mistake of me. Somehow I overwrote manage.py. @mouad you were right. My default editor textmate stopped working, and i was using textwrangler for the first time and must have done some stupid mistake. Thanks a lot for the help. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Shall I delete the question or leave it?

Comment: Happened to me just now, file got corrupted somehow. Had to recreate the project. Would never think to check the file if this post was not here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if python is fully installed by typing "python" in a shell.

Then you should try `python manage.py runserver` inside your django project. If you don't have any django project, try creating one by typing `django-admin.py startproject mysite`. If nothing is displayed in your shell, you must have installed Django the wrong way.

Please refer to Django Documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/install/

Comment: Hey phemios

Python is installed. >> python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

Also I am running everything from inside the project folder (the one that contains manage.py)

Installed django through that link. I'm trying to do everything through the book.

Comment: Ok, it turns out to be a very stupid oversight. More info on upper comment. Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: This did not work for me. I was running into the same issue (better described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707336/django-nothing-happens-when-i-enter-python-manage-py-runserver?noredirect=1&lq=1), what worked was adding --noreload. I didn't continue to debug to figure out why, but posting here in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that the first line in `manage.py` breaks the file on windows.
The first line should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Removing it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you had your server running till one point and a certain action/change broke it, try going back to the previous state.

In my case there was an email trigger which would put the system in an invalid state if email doesn't go through. Doing `git stash` followed by selectively popping the stash and trying the `runserver` helps narrow down the problem to a particular file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

1. Uninstall Python.
2. Go inside C drive and search Django. You will get many Django related files.
3. Delete every Django file.  don't delete your Django files.
4. Install Python.

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you created a virtual environment then activate it. you can try this command(in virtual environment directory) if you're using windows os:

```
.\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu works for my by running `manage.py` as script:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stuck with the same problem. Found a solution that works, but tedious.

You need to know the location of the python.exe file in your computer. It is usually
C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python//python.exe

Modify as required and run the following in CMD,

```
C:/Users/USER1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe
F:/mysite/manage.py runserver
```

Hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Redis Server on Windows, check it out if Redis Server is running, I had same problem and realized my Redis Server was not running, I ran it and now my manage.py commands work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with me also, but this issue is a minor one as it happens if you have multiple versions of Python on your system, you can select a specific Python version by running python3 or whichever version you want.
SO you should start from the beginning, uninstall Django first then,
create a virtual environment, decide upon a directory where you want to place it, and run the venv module as a script with the directory path:

for e.g:
python3 -m venv tutorial-env

//This will create the tutorial-env directory if it doesn’t exist, and also create directories inside it
Once you’ve created a virtual environment, you may activate it.

On Windows, run:

tutorial-env\Scripts\activate.bat
On Unix or MacOS, run:

source tutorial-env/bin/activate

Now,
In the command prompt, ensure your virtual environment is active, and execute the following command:

...> py -m pip install Django

NOTE:
If django-admin only displays the help text no matter what arguments it is given, there is probably a problem with the file association in Windows. Check if there is more than one environment variable set for running Python scripts in PATH. This usually occurs when there is more than one Python version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you can, is to upgrade Django

```
pip install django --upgrade
```

Oftentimes one will get other unrelated issues to solve that are linked with the upgrade but once all is fixed the server should run just fine.

If you can't upgrade Django, this problem also happens when the code was built using Python 2.x and you're locally using Python 3.x.

The quicker fix in that case is to uninstall Python 3.x from your machine and make sure Python 2.x was added to the path. I've seen some developers setting up alias in PowerShell to have more than one version in the environment too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in manage.py file, check it with

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in manage.py file (50%), check it with an another file that is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have established successfully database connection