# Django /manage.py runserver doesn't work (Windows)

Tags: python, django

I have installed python 2.7.10 in windows. I installed django in path `c:python27/scripts/`with a command `pip install django` and created project with command `django-admin startproject mysite` from the same path.

Now to run server i cd to path `c:python27/scripts/mysite` and ran a command `manage.py runserver`/ `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` And this has no any effect.

where did i go wrong, and also i couldn't run with python console. and i couldn't redirect to my project from python CMD. all i did is from windows console.

**Edit:**
Screenshot of execution
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "this has no any effect"? It must do something.. Any errors?

Comment: @Sayse it doesn't execute like it's saying in the doc. and it doesn't prints any error. moves to next line.

Comment: is your manage.py file executable ? What happens if you type "python manage.py runserver" instead ?

Comment: Try out with python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 or you can also try ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the result is `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Try python manage.py runserver.If the python command not find,you should add the python bin to your environment variable.

Comment: @Ymartin same result with `/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000!` no luck

Comment: @RicoTeng it says `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` may be need to add python bin to environment variable...

Comment: @SumanK.C Yeah, You should add python to your environment variable.

Comment: @RicoTeng yes that was it. Thank you, cheers !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing happens when I do: python manage.py command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491529/nothing-happens-when-i-do-python-manage-py-command)

Comment: My issue is I always type main.py runserver 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First step was to set the environment variable.

- `windows key` + `pause` or `Control Panel\System and Security\System`
- Advance system settings (this will open system property)
- navigate to `Advanced tab` > `Environment variable`
- Edit path - append `;c:\python27` in variable value field
- Restart CMD

then `/python manage.py runserver` should work

Answer (score 2):

Trying setting up a virtualenv for your project.

This same issue happened to me when trying to launch the test server

```
python .\manage.py runserver
```

from PowerShell on Windows 10. According to the Django site, there might be an issue with the type of arguments being passed from PowerShell.

My workaround was to use a virtualenv. Once that was setup with django installed via pip, the runserver command worked.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to install Python from *Microsoft Store*. In this case, you won't have to worry about the Environmental Variables and Path. Windows will detect all that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fix guys:
1. Right click on the windows icon/start on the bottom left and run Windows Powershell as admin.
2. Than type `cd ~/` and later change the path again to the project folder.
3. type `python manage.py runserver` and press enter.

Comment: By the way, since I use a windows machine, using *py -3 manage.py runserver* instead of "python3 ..." also worked.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. fixed it by checking *python and django version compatibility*. If you're still battling with this update one or the other or ensure they're both compatible with each other in the virtual'env' you're setting up.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add python to environment variables. So, During the installation, click the checkbox named "Add Python 3.9 to PATH" to add in environment variables. or you can simply add the path later.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you open the command prompt on windows, the default directory might be **C:\WINDOWS\System32>**
Here, you have to change the directory by just adding **cd** to the default directory. Then copy the directory of where your project is and paste with one space. So it will be:
**C:\yourfolder\yourproject>**
Next, use the comman which is, python manage.py runserver

That's all

Answer (score -1):

After setting `C:\Python` in the environment variables, issuing the following command helped:

```
py manage.py runserver
```