# Django: Nothing happens when I enter "python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've installed Django inside a virtualenv on an AWS EC2 Windows Server instance. I created a project `mysite` and then cd'd into that directory, and when I run `python manage.py runserver` like the documentation says to, nothing happens. It starts a new line in the bash shell with no output and then ends when I Ctrl-C.

Edit: This is what I see in the shell.

```
Administrator@WIN-EBB5RSRPK9T MINGW64 /c/venv/mysite
$ python -m django --version
1.10
(venv)
Administrator@WIN-EBB5RSRPK9T MINGW64 /c/venv/mysite
$ python manage.py runserver

Administrator@WIN-EBB5RSRPK9T MINGW64 /c/venv/mysite
$
```

Comment: do you have django installed? please provide what you're seeing in your shell

Comment: @marcusshep edited

Comment: What documentation did you follow?

Comment: @error2007s I went back to the official Django tutorial to jog my memory on how to start an app https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I was running into the same issue, and it was only fixed by adding --noreload when running the runserver command.