# python manage.py runserver doesn't display anything

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, backend

I used to work with django and I didn't face this problem in the past, Then I shifted for a while to Laravel ( and sure I changed a lot of things in the windows which I don't remember ).

and now when I hit `python manage.py runserver` .. nothing happen and the shell seems as it hanged . hover once I hit crt + C .the normal window suddenly appear that says :

> You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly
>   until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes,
>   sessions. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them. January 08,
>   2019 - 14:16:30 Django version 2.1.1, using settings
>   'django_project.settings' Starting development server at
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

However I am able to go to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and I have the welcome page of django with this line added [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwJ8n.png)

It sounds crazy I know , please excuse me cause I am a newbie and thanx in advance

Comment: What's not working for you ? At what point of time `http://127.0.0.1:8000` is working ? Did you tried applying migrations ?

Comment: No, I didn't apply migration yet , but as I know that once I hit python manage.py runserver .. the shell window appear whch says 'django_project.settings' Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK. and what about the debug part in the welcome page

Comment: What's not working for you ?

Comment: Are you using different database?

Comment: I faced many problems since then and I figured a solution for it . is to add winpty before any order on the shell .. it is confusing but do you know why even for winpty python manage.py createsuperuser –

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing happens when I do: python manage.py command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491529/nothing-happens-when-i-do-python-manage-py-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've to apply migrations.

You've just to run what he says:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I think it's better to look at the documentation before you proceed: you've to understand how models work in Django.
Take a look [to the documentation first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/).
And my advice is to follow the "first app" tutorial. Go [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 2):

The first line in manage.py breaks the file on windows. The first line should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

**Removing** it will fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

To apply migrations run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Seems like you've just installed django and every time you do so, you should apply the migrations. This synchronizes the database state with your current set of models and migrations.

[More about migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/migrations/)

Comment: but is there any miss configuration that rise due to miss configuration in the local host cause that changes that i've done for Laravel, ?? as i remember I changed some parameters file in windows32 or somthing like that is the windows files

Comment: sorry if it seems stupid, but this is driving me crazy cause I used to work in Django and I never faced a problem in runserver !!!!

Comment: Did you run python manage.py migrate? Seems like everything is fine. Just run that and you should be good.

Comment: I faced many problems since then and I figured a solution for it . is to add winpty before any order on the shell .. it is confusing but do you know why even for winpty python manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py runserver` works correctly.