# python manage.py runserver is not working

Tags: python, django, pip

So before anyone point it out, my question is really similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091741/python-manage-py-runserver-doesnt-display-anything/54092027) but the error message is slightly different.

So I just started learning Django this day and I got stuck because when I ran `python manage.py runserver` it didn't display anything until I hit "CTRL + C" then this message showed up

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 30, 2020 - 15:51:40
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'trydjangofcc.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
(mine)
```

I tried to go to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and it didn't work, I've tried `python manage.py migrate` still nothing.
I've waited an hour to see if it makes a difference and it doesn't. It seems stupid but I've been stuck here for a while.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: "Windows " is it because of that?

Comment: Not necessarily, but just I think it would be worth looking at the TCP connection status in case packets are not getting through, and this will be OS-dependent. (I can't help with Windows I'm afraid.) Guessing that you might have some local firewall issue.

Comment: The message seems the same as I get in Linux when starting runserver successfully (aside from different key to quit), so I guess that it started okay and something in the OS is just not letting clients connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try entering this into your URL bar :
http://localhost:8000/

Comment: You're right actually. For some reason the terminal didn't display anything but the server is still running, Thanks man !

Comment: No worries mate glad I could help !

Answer (score 0):

try these steps:

1. run application with different port number, for example use 9000 as your port number, try this: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:9000
2. check your hosts file (in windows 10: C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts or in centos: /etc/hosts ) and search for 127.0.0.1, it may redirect "127.0.0.1" to defferent url not localhost

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same issue for close to 19 hours. I did all the stuffs until I realised a line of code was mistakenly removed from the manage.py file.

I browsed other app I have and I discovered it.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

the message you got isn't an error, that exactly what manage.py runserver does..

Just click on the link. It will open the server.
Oh, and CTRL+C mean  CANCEL an action

Comment: but the terminal didn't display anything that's why I'm intentionally canceling the process with CRTL +  C  cause I've waited for like an hour and then that message showed up it's really weird

Answer (score -1):

Make sure after running the server you DO NOT USE crl+C, as it is canceling the server.
for copying the URL use right click and copy.