# manage.py runserver not doing anything

Tags: python, django

Upon using this command, nothing happens. No error or anything. Python is in environment variables and I'm not having any problem with the python directory. I am running the most recent versions of Django and Python.

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umZ9R.png)

Code in manage.py, freshly created, didn't change anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is really weird, can you check file manage.py content? And please post your problem as code, not image

Comment: I added the code to the post, the project was just created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing happens when I do: python manage.py command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491529/nothing-happens-when-i-do-python-manage-py-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't have a clear cut answer for you, and I am no expert, but this is what I would suggest.

Try `py manage.py check` to self check your django app.

Try `py -m django --version` to ensure django is installed.

Try `py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`. (I need this as some firewall or setting prevents me from running on default port 8000. But I do get an error message about forbidden socket permissions.)

Are you in a virtual environment? Creating a V.E. and installing dependencies and running from within V.E. can ensure the only packages installed and accessible are the ones your project requires and thus avoids conflicts/problems. I don't know that this will solve this problem, but it is best practice.

Comment: Oddly enough, manage.py check does not work either. Django is installed to the latest version, and I'm not in a virtual environment.

Comment: Try entering `pip freeze` to show all the packages installed in your current environment. If this is a long list beyond what you need for this project it means there is potential for conflict. Which is where virtual environments are useful. If you create new V.E, activate, and `pip freeze` there is nothing, a blank slate. Once again not sure this will solve your problem but it is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: in window `py` is the Python launcher, I think it's not problem here

Comment: Well, that seems ok.