# Nothing happens when I use: python manage.py command

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in coding and I just started watching a Django tutorial by net ninja and it got to a point that I have to use `python manage.py runserver` and it does just nothing but I did everything exactly like in the video.
I searched the internet and found some people that have the same problem but no answer to it. Here is the video that I learn from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAE94gzgQvI&t=223s .

Comment: No, it just can't do nothing. It will runserver or it will throw error.... You have to add tracebacks also.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing happens when I do: python manage.py command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491529/nothing-happens-when-i-do-python-manage-py-command)