# I am working on DjangoRest project whenever i try to execute command python manage.py runserver or python manage.py shell It won't work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my settings.py file and I've created a .env file which contains secret key and other stuffs. I tried installing reinstalling python changing path deleting and again adding project and even I reinstalled vs code but it won't work i dont know where's the problem. [This command python manage.py runserver or python manage.py shell or any other related commmand won't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVMQo.png)

```
"""Settings.py"""
"""
Django settings for doorstepdelhi project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from decouple import config
import django_heroku
import os
from pathlib import Path


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config("DEBUG", default=False, cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    "versatileimagefield",
    "nested_admin",
    'drf_yasg',
    "django_extensions",
    'channels',

    "accounts",
    "webtraffic",
    "store",
    "product",
    "shop",
    "wishlist",
    "payment",
    'core',
    "room",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "core.middleware.LogMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "doorstepdelhi.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "doorstepdelhi.wsgi.application"
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'doorstepdelhi.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Kolkata"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static")

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

SITE_ID = 1

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
DEFAULT_DECIMAL_PLACES = 3
DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS = 12

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny",),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": ["django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend"],
    "DATETIME_FORMAT": "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S",
}

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"

ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"

EMAIL_URL = os.environ.get("EMAIL_URL")
SENDGRID_USERNAME = os.environ.get("SENDGRID_USERNAME")
SENDGRID_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("SENDGRID_PASSWORD")
if not EMAIL_URL and SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD:
    EMAIL_URL = "smtp://%s:%s@smtp.sendgrid.net:587/?tls=True" % (
        SENDGRID_USERNAME,
        SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
    )

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.UserSerializer",
}


VERSATILEIMAGEFIELD_RENDITION_KEY_SETS = {
    "products": [
        ("product_gallery", "thumbnail__540x540"),
        ("product_gallery_2x", "thumbnail__1080x1080"),
        ("product_small", "thumbnail__60x60"),
        ("product_small_2x", "thumbnail__120x120"),
        ("product_list", "thumbnail__255x255"),
        ("product_list_2x", "thumbnail__510x510"),
    ],
    "background_images": [("header_image", "thumbnail__1080x440")],
    "user_avatars": [("default", "thumbnail__445x445")],
}

# VERSATILEIMAGEFIELD_SETTINGS = {
#     # Images should be pre-generated on Production environment
#     "create_images_on_demand": get_bool_from_env("CREATE_IMAGES_ON_DEMAND", DEBUG)
# }

PLACEHOLDER_IMAGES = {
    60: "images/placeholder60x60.png",
    120: "images/placeholder120x120.png",
    255: "images/placeholder255x255.png",
    540: "images/placeholder540x540.png",
    1080: "images/placeholder1080x1080.png",
}

# EMAIL
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config("EMAIL_USE_TLS")
EMAIL_USE_SSL = config("EMAIL_USE_SSL")
EMAIL_HOST = config("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_PORT = config("EMAIL_PORT")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = config("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL")


# CELERY
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6379/0")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6379/0")
# CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
# CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
# CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://redis:6379/0",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
        "KEY_PREFIX": "doorstepdelhi",
    }
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())


PAYTM_MERCHANT_ID = config("PAYTM_MERCHANT_ID")
PAYTM_SECRET_KEY = config("PAYTM_SECRET_KEY")
PAYTM_WEBSITE = config("PAYTM_WEBSITE")
PAYTM_CHANNEL_ID = config("PAYTM_CHANNEL_ID")
PAYTM_INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = config("PAYTM_INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID")
```

This is the manage.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "doorstepdelhi.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is "where python" output

```
C:\Users\hp>where python
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\New folder\Doorstep-Delhi-Back-end\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

Comment: Also all other projects of django or djangorest are working fine on my desktop

Comment: Show the _contents_ of `manage.py` and also the output of `where python` (or `which python` if you use Linux)

Comment: sir for output i've added an image in the question and I have edited the question please check that.

Comment: Not that output, give the output of `where python` (Also don't add it as an image, I don't see why it needs to be an image... See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: Okay I've added where python please check out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing happens when I do: python manage.py command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491529/nothing-happens-when-i-do-python-manage-py-command)

Comment: no it doesn't work