# Python Manage.py runserver Failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have virtual environment of window 10 of company laptop. I am trying to execute

```
python manage.py
```

or

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Not getting error and it just shows output like this-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQg14.png)

I expect the runserver start in my virtual environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing happens when I do: python manage.py command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491529/nothing-happens-when-i-do-python-manage-py-command)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, My django is working when i use any command with django-admin startproject but when i use python manage,py it doesn't show anything

Comment: How is this related to the link I provided in the previous comment? Have you tried that solution?

Comment: Yeah! I tried the solution

Answer (score 0):

use venv or make sure the paths are correct

```
py -m venv nameEnv
.\nameEnv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

Comment: Hi @skaz I tried to run the venv command. After that i run python manage.py it says
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exceptio

Comment: After running the venv, use pip install django and then repeat py manage.py runserver